# Python Executable Crashes in Conda Environment

Tags: python, conda, executable

Let's say I have two files we'll call `test1.py` and `test2.py`, and I want to run both of these files as executables. I'm familiar with the standard procedure of adding a shebang followed by the path to the desired python interpreter and then running `chmod u="rwx" file.py`.

I also know that when using conda, each environment gets its own unique interpreter with which to run scripts. So naturally, I activate my environment, run `which python` and add that command's output to my script like so...

**test1.py**

```
#!/home/my_name/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
print("foo")
```

Which when I run it as `./test1.py` gives me the following error...

```
./test1.py: line 2: syntax error near unexpected token `"foo"'
./test1.py: line 2: `print("foo")'
```

However simply running `python test1.py` gives...

```
foo
```

Now let's say I return to my base environment and following the same procedure as above, I create the following script...

**test2.py**

```
#!/home/my_name/anaconda3/bin/python
print("foo")
```

This script runs without error and gives the correct output regardless of whether or not I run it as an executable.

What do I need to do in order to run my python scripts without these errors?

**EDIT**

Running `which python` in `env_name` gives

```
/home/my_name/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python
```

Whereas running the same command in `base` gives

```
/home/my_name/anaconda3/bin/python
```

Comment: I'm not sure I understand your question.  Are you saying that, if the command prompt, you type `python test1.py`, and hit Return, the code prints `"foo"`.  But if you run the same script by just typing `testt1.py` and hitting Return,  the program outputs the error message you show.  Am I correct so far?   But all this only for `test1.py`.  You can run `test2.py` either way and this script runs correctly.  Do I have it all right?

Comment: Please add to your question what you get if you run `which python`, so we know which version of Python is running your scripts when you do `python X`.

Comment: How, exactly, are you executing the python script in the first example?

Comment: What happens if you run `/home/my_name/anaconda3/envs/env_name/bin/python` inside the environment?

Comment: Is the Python in the **env_name** environment Python 2?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue when line 1 was empty, and the interpreter was set in line 2. This results in bash assuming that it's a bash script, and as a result, you get a "syntax error" from trying to execute python commands in bash.